# What does tracking do in BF4 and what are field upgrades?

Tags: battlefield-4

When you like level up does some of that score go in the tracking things?
How do you get the field upgrade score and what do they do?

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question when the game came out.
[Here you can find all your answers to your questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/141455/what-is-this-called)
But to answer your question. They are perks given by doing certain thing in game with your squad.